# Schengen visa for married couple

Tags: visas, schengen, international-travel

My husband has invitation letter from his work company in Amsterdam. He will apply for **business visa** shorter than 90 days. In this case which type of visa spouse need to apply and what documents should I show (as I am housewife) for *Schengen visa*?

Comment: As far as I know, the short stay business visa it is the same type is the tourist visa. Both of you should apply the same type of visa and ass him as your sponsor.

Comment: Thank you. So if we get invitation letter from Europe thats enough I think.